# Composition of Continuous functions with a finite number of points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, real-numbers

Suppose $f$ is continuous everywhere except for a finite number of points and $g$ is continuous everywhere. Then show $g \circ f$ is continuous everywhere except for a finite number of points. Show that this does not hold for $f \circ g$.

I know that the composition of a continuous function is continuous proof and that just intuitively say $X$ is the set of points of a finite number of points where $f$ is discontinuous then any $x \in X$ for $f(x)$ is going to be non-existent and thus $g(f(x))$ is non-existent and discontinuous at $f(X)$. So dimension wise field of $f(x)$ is less equal to field of $x$ since it is a function. But this is not rigorous I think. Is there a better way?

Comment: Example:  suppose $f$ is defined everywhere except $x=2$.  Then let $g=\sin x$.  (Comment is designed to get you thinking in this direction; I do not suppose it is anything close to what you want to write, precisely.)

Answer (score 1):

Since this has been tagged real-analysis and real-numbers, I'll assume that these are real-valued functions.

Claim: Let $X$ be the finite set of points where $f$ is not continuous.  Then $g\circ f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus X$.  Let $y\in \mathbb{R}\setminus X$.

- Approach $1$:  Consider $\lim_{z\rightarrow y}g\circ f(z)$.  Since $g$ is continuous, this equals $g(\lim_{z\rightarrow y}f(z))$.  Since $f$ is continuous at $y$, this equals $g(f(\lim_{z\rightarrow y}z))=g\circ f(y)$.  Therefore, $g\circ f$ is continuous at $y$.
- Approach $2$ (using $\varepsilon-\delta$): For $y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus X$, the proof that the composition of continuous functions is continuous works (as long as you further restrict $\delta$ so that $(y-\delta,y+\delta)$ does not intersect $X$ (but this restriction is allowed).

For the counterexample for $f\circ g$.  Suppose that $g$ is a continuous function that achieves the non-continuous values of $f$ infinitely often.  Then $f\circ g$ may be discontinuous whenever this occurs.  For example, let $f(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(x)$, i.e., $f$ applied to positive values is $1$, $f(0)=0$, and $f$ applied to negative values is $-1$.  Let $g(x)=\sin(x)$.  Then $f\circ g$ keeps alternating between $1$, $0$, and $-1$.  In particular, it is discontinuous at multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: why is "since $f$ is continuous at $y$, this equals $g(f(\lim_{z\rightarrow y}z))=g\circ f(y)$"? and is z any point in R?

Comment: The definition of continuous at $y$ is that $f(y)=\lim_{z\rightarrow y}f(z)$.  In other words, if $z$ is close enough to $y$, then $f(z)$ and $f(y)$ are close.  $z$ is a "dummy" variable, so it could be any point in $\mathbb{R}$, but we're looking at its behavior as it gets close to $y$.